# The sum of a sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, formula, continued-fractions

I'm trying to make a function for calculating this formula

[image: formula]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
double Sequence(std::vector < double > & a) {
  double result = 0;
  for (int i = a.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (a[i] == 0) throw std::domain_error("Dividing with 0");
    if (i > 1)
      result += 1 / (a[i - 1] + 1 / a[i]);
    else result += a[i - i];
    std::cout << a[i] << " " << result << " " << "\n";
  }
  return result;
}
int main() {
  std::vector<double>a{1,2,3,4,5};
  try {
    std::cout << Sequence(a);
  } catch (std::domain_error e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Code gives correct result for {1,2,3} sequence. However, if I add a few numbers to that sequence result becomes wrong. Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: Recommendation: Step through the program with a debugger and keep an eye out for where the program first deviates from your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i > 1)
  result += 1 / (a[i - 1] + 1 / a[i]);
else result += a[i - i];
```

This is wrong; it just happens to work if you have three or fewer terms.

The recurrence you actually want is

```
if (i == a.size() - 1) {
    result = a[i];
} else {
    result = a[i] + 1 / result;
}
```

you can see that this is a correct recurrence by the fact that
Tidying up some more things (removing the condition from inside the loop, fixing an off-by-one in the loop termination condition, and correcting the exception condition):

```
double Sequence(std::vector<double> &a) {
  double result = a[a.size() - 1];
  for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (result == 0)
      throw std::domain_error("Dividing with 0");
    result = a[i] + 1 / result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This known as the Simple Continued Fraction where all numerators are 1s. It is basically represented as `[a1;a2,a3,...,an]` (well in fact starts from `a0` but whatever). You can calculate the result from top to bottom while obtaining a better approximation (or *convergent* as they call it) at each step.

The result of this finite rational series or infinite irrational series is expressed as `p/q`. In order to calculate the result you assume

```
p0   1     p1   a1       p2   a2*p1+p0      p3   a3*p2+p1            pn   a_n*p_n-1+p_n-2
__ = _ and __ = __ then  __ = ________ then __ = ________ .. then .. __ = _______________
q0   0     q1   1        q2   a2*q1+q0      q3   a3*q2+q1            qn   a_n*q_n-1+q_n-2
```

and every next `p_x/q_x` yields a better appoximation to the result.

Say if you are given a decimal like `1.425` in continued fraction cefficients as

```
[1; 2, 2, 1, 5]
```

a.k.a.

```
          1
1 + _____________
            1
    2 + _________
              1
        2 + _____
                1
            1 + _
                5
```

Then the intermediate convergents calculated as described above would be;

```
1    1    3    7    10    57
_ -> _ -> _ -> _ -> __ -> __ = 1.425
0    1    2    5    7     40
```

Notice that each convergent overshoots up and down from the final result subsequently besides `57/40` being the minimal rational expression of `1.425`.

Continued fractions are a very deep topic which in fact eliminates the floating point error once an arithmetic is establised among them in their continued fractions form.

You can play [here](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/cfCALC.html).